# Python permutation difference

Tags: python

Is there something built-in to tell the permutation difference between two list?  E.g.

```
difference("ijk", "ikj") = (0,2,1)
difference("jik", "ikj") = (2,0,1)
etc ...
```

oops, nevermind, here is a snippet

```
[a.index(i) for i in b]
```

Comment: Please define `permutation difference`

Comment: that's a puzzle, you have to first figure out what the question is :/

Comment: @Dae the indices to transform one list into another.

Comment: i told you it's a puzzle, here is the next clue

Comment: i think that means the difference between two lists of permutations? or maybe the permutations between the difference ... or ... ugh! ... I'd write something myself if i were you.

Comment: So basically the strings use the same characters but scrambled and you want to determine what indies of the second string would make the first.  There's nothing built-in to do that, it's way too specialized to be useful in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple...

```
def difference(after, before):
    return tuple(before.index(x) for x in after)

print difference('ijk', 'ikj') # (0, 2, 1)
print difference('jik', 'ikj') # (2, 0, 1)
```

Comment: It seems like this might give a "wrong" result if there are duplicates in the input sets.  I guess the problem would need better specification to know if that matters though.

Comment: Good point. In that case multiple answers are possible - it's ambiguous.

Comment: For example, `difference('iii', 'iii')` could return anything from `(0, 1, 2)` to `(2, 1, 0)` and every other permutation. But this solution would return `(0, 0, 0)` which is perhaps not good.

Answer (score 2):

Is this short enough?

```
tuple([s2.index(p) for p in s1])
```